# How can i check if my DOM already contains an element by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, kendo-ui

I would like to know if it is possible to check if my DOM contains an element id. Actually I dynamically load my templates (kendo templates) and append them in my body.

```
<body>
    ...

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="test-view">
        ...
    </script>
</body>
```

At this moment my loading script is

```
//Creates a gloabl object called templateLoader with a single method "loadExtTemplate"
var templateLoader = (function ($, host) {
    //Loads external templates from path and injects in to page DOM
    return {
        //Method: loadExtTemplate
        //Params: (string) path: the relative path to a file that contains template definition(s)
        loadExtTemplate: function (path) {
            //Use jQuery Ajax to fetch the template file
            var tmplLoader = $.get(path)
                .success(function (result) {
                    //On success, Add templates to DOM (assumes file only has template definitions)
                    var regSplit = new RegExp("[/\]+", "g");
                    var pathTab = path.split(regSplit);
                    var templateName = pathTab[pathTab.length - 1];
                    var regReplace = new RegExp("[.]+", "g");
                    var templateName = templateName.replace(regReplace, "-");
                    var s = $("<script type=\"text/x-kendo-template\" id=\"" + templateName + "\">" + result + "</script>");
                    $("body").append(s);
                })
                .error(function (result) {
                    alert("Error Loading Templates -- TODO: Better Error Handling");
                })

            tmplLoader.complete(function () {
                //Publish an event that indicates when a template is done loading
                $(host).trigger("TEMPLATE_LOADED", [path]);
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, document);
```

Before loading my template I need to check if this one is already loaded. I need to check if a script with the id="test-view" exists or not. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not just look for the element via jQuery or `document.getElementById()`???

Comment: Because I'm noob with JS and I still discover jQuery. I tried the documentation before asking the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var element = $('#' + templateName)
if(!element.length) {
   // create your template
}
```

Comment: `!element` will always be false as it's a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: Ahh, actually, yes. element.length is more appropriate. Updated.

Comment: `if(!element.length)` will evaluate to true even if the element is undefined. `!0 == true`

Comment: The key here is how you're checking the element length. `if(ele2.length)`. Note the lack of a `!`, which reverses the condition.

Comment: Not trying to be argumentative here, but are you sure? Look here http://jsfiddle.net/hr6fV/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var elementExists = (document.getElementById("elementId") !== null);
```

`elementExists` will now contain a boolean that tells you whether or not the element already exists.

Comment: @Matt Could you explain me why?

Comment: Matt, you're right. I assumed it would return `undefined` if it can't find the element. Instead it returns `null`. Editing to fix.

Comment: @B413 `typeof document.getElementById("elementId")` always returns `object`, because even `null` is an object.

Comment: ...and that is why we have the abstract comparison operators (and `!`).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding

```
if(document.getElementById(templateName)) return;
```

after

```
var templateName = templateName.replace(regReplace, "-");
```

So your code becomes:

```
.success(function (result) {
    //On success, Add templates to DOM (assumes file only has template definitions)
    var regSplit = new RegExp("[/\]+", "g");
    var pathTab = path.split(regSplit);
    var templateName = pathTab[pathTab.length - 1];
    var regReplace = new RegExp("[.]+", "g");
    var templateName = templateName.replace(regReplace, "-");
    if(document.getElementById(templateName)) return;
    var s = $("<script type=\"text/x-kendo-template\" id=\"" + templateName + "\">" + result + "</script>");
    $("body").append(s);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using length or size:

eg,

```
$("#test-view").length //$("#test-view").size()
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure we already have this answer, and a better version of it, at that.

Comment: Are u refering to $("#test-view").size()

Comment: I am referring to how your answer seems similar to Chris Dixon's, but not as good.

Comment: Is not this fiddle solve this issue ? wonder what is looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/9R9FW/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
if ($("#test-view").length) {...}
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("#test-view").length) {...}
```

And a couple comments:

- [html4] id is not a regular attribute for the script tag (but AFAIK all browsers support it)
- the above code works for any selector, not just ids
- querySelectorAll is not supported in IE7